# Adding onclick link on response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a return from a request set like:

```
if (ajaxRequest.responseText==234) {
    document.getElementById('testi').innerHTML="<br>test <a href='#' onclick="document.getElementById('others').value += 'asdasd';">test</a><br> ";
}
```

'Others' is a text area box.  Testi is a div used to display the results of the request.

But the link does not appear.  If I remove the onclick part it works, so I suspect that is the problem.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the double quotes inside the double quotes.

```
document.getElementById('testi').innerHTML="<br>test <a href='#' onclick=\"document.getElementById('others').value += 'asdasd';\">test</a><br> ";
```